# A config file to hold all REST apis

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have lot of Backbone models like these:

```
var register = Backbone.model.extend({
url: http://....../register/
});

var login = Backbone.model.extend({
url: http://....../login/
});
```

My question is:

Can i have a separate file to hold all urls? Like a file which holds all the urls and I can request with a variable name as needed? Is it a bad approach?  I want to be able to change these apis without going to model file(s) individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a file, for instance, appUrl like this:

```
app.urls = { 
    registerUrl: "/register", 
    loginUrl: "/login"
}
```

and your model:

```
var register = Backbone.model.extend({
    url: function(){
       return app.urls['registerUrl']
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to pass in the URL in the instantiation of the model, rather than declaring explicit models for each. That would look something like:

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // My shared model properties
});

var myNewModel = new BaseModel(null, {
    url: '/my-url-for-new-model'
});
```

Alternately, you can have the `url` parameter be a function, and then return the appropriate URL. That could be something like this:

```
var urls = {
    register: '/some-url/register/',
    login: '/some-url/login'
};

var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(data, config) {
        this.modelType = config.type;
    }
    url: function() {
        return urls[this.modelType];
    }
});

var loginModel = new BaseModel(null, {
    type: login
});
```